# I am unable to open Ubuntu Software & Updates, Sofware Updater and Software Boutique

Tags: 16.04, apt, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE. I am trying to open Ubuntu Software & Updates and Software Updater. So, I clicked on Control Center and I am clicking on **Software & Updates** and **Software Updater**. But they are not opening.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for souvik: 

...               
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu xenial Release              
  404  Not Found
...                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please open terminal and execute `sudo apt update`. And add error output  to the question (if any). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using "MATE Desktop Environment 1.12.1". I am getting the following error after that command  "sudo apt update".Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu xenial Release              
  404  Not Found

Answer (score 0):

The PPA from your error message is [outdated and no longer maintained](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/ubuntu/emacs), so we need to remove it with commands below:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:cassou/emacs
```

if this command fails - remove this PPA from the system with another command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:cassou/emacs
```

And then you can use your system as before. As starting point you may want to install all updates:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the first two commands are not working. E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cassou/emacs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: Then try to remove this PPA from the system with other command: `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:cassou/emacs`.

Comment: Now it is showing this..... File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Comment: Then you should reinstall one package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt`.

Comment: I tried with that command and then I did sudo apt update and it showing me "Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default". Then I use the command sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:cassou/emacs but as usual it is showing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' ".