# Red circle(minus) mark on the right top of the screen

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

I am very new user to the Ubuntu MATE. One red circle is appearing on the right top of the screen. Don't know why? Maybe because of it I am not being able to open Software & Updates and Software Boutique.

Comment: Please add screenshot of this red circle and/or click on it and add screenshot of elements shown.

Comment: What happened in your [previous question?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087852/i-am-unable-to-open-ubuntu-software-updates-sofware-updater-and-software-bout). It would be helpful to you and others if you respond to people who provide answers or comments to your previous questions.

Comment: I am not being able to attach image. But it showing me the following : A problem occurred when checking for the updates.    Show Updates     Show notifications     Preferences

Comment: Not sure without any screenshot at this time, but the "red circle(minus)" mark looks like the dialog-error status icon?

Comment: How do I insert an image here ?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the topbar with the red circle https://imgur.com/a/p1Qa2Vb